# JavaScript Button not showing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add Javascript button to code-block dynamically, but the button is not showing when created dynamically.

I am using code-syntax highlighting library [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/)

Please mention or reply, the work-through for this

**[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/dsmith33/1j2r74e8/5/)**

In console, I can add button, but I can not add button with Javascript. Please see, where I am doing wrong.

Updated the JSfiddle link, I am trying to loop with foreach loop.

```js
var y = document.querySelectorAll("pre code");
  for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    y[i].innerHTML = y[i].innerHTML.replace("\n", "");
    }
    
const codeSyn = document.querySelectorAll("pre code tbody tr");
const redhTML = '<span><button class="btnCopy badge bg-secondary">copy</button></span>';
codeSyn.forEach(tr =>{
tr.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', redhTML);
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing HighlightJS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/styles/routeros.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Testing HighlightJS Multiple blocks</h3>
    <h4>First Code block</h4>
    <pre><code class="language-css">
    .class{
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: monospace;
    }
    h1 .header{
    font-size: 1.5rem;;
    font-family: Arial;
    }
    </code></pre>
    
    <h4>Second Code block</h4>
    <pre><code class="language-css">
    .class{
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: monospace;
    }
    h1 .header{
    font-size: 1.5rem;;
    font-family: Arial;
    }
    </code></pre>
    
    <h4>Third Code block</h4>
    <pre><code class="language-css">
    .class{
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: monospace;
    }
    h1 .header{
    font-size: 1.5rem;;
    font-family: Arial;
    }
    </code></pre>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/languages/css.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlightjs-line-numbers.js/2.6.0/highlightjs-line-numbers.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.highlightAll(); hljs.initLineNumbersOnLoad();</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your current code right ? It should be `codeSyn` instead of `codesyn` before `forEach`.

Comment: edited the code and JSFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no table present you should change this:

```
const codeSyn = document.querySelectorAll("pre code tbody tr");
```

to this:

```
const codeSyn = document.querySelectorAll("pre code");
```

In the `insertAdjacentHTML()` method you should change `'beforeend'` to `'afterbegin'` so the buttons get added as the first child of the `<code>` elements.

And finally, add some `CSS` for the button to be positioned in the top-right corner:

```
span > button.btnCopy {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 10px;
}

code {
    position: relative;
}
```

The `code { position: relative; }` was added to be able to properly position the button element within the `<code>` element since the button is positioned as `position: absolute`.

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8rcjgubk/2/).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you arrived at having `tbody tr` in the selector since those are not present in the DOM. Removing them works as you intended :-

```js
var y = document.querySelectorAll("pre code");
  for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    y[i].innerHTML = y[i].innerHTML.replace("\n", "");
    }
    
const codeSyn = document.querySelectorAll("pre code");
const redhTML = '<span class="copy"><button class="btnCopy badge bg-secondary">copy</button></span>';
codeSyn.forEach(tr =>{
tr.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', redhTML);
})
```

```css
.copy{
position:absolute;
right:0;
}

pre{
position:relative
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing HighlightJS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/styles/routeros.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Testing HighlightJS Multiple blocks</h3>
    <h4>First Code block</h4>
    <pre><code class="language-css">
    .class{
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: monospace;
    }
    h1 .header{
    font-size: 1.5rem;;
    font-family: Arial;
    }
    </code></pre>
    
    <h4>Second Code block</h4>
    <pre><code class="language-css">
    .class{
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: monospace;
    }
    h1 .header{
    font-size: 1.5rem;;
    font-family: Arial;
    }
    </code></pre>
    
    <h4>Third Code block</h4>
    <pre><code class="language-css">
    .class{
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: monospace;
    }
    h1 .header{
    font-size: 1.5rem;;
    font-family: Arial;
    }
    </code></pre>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/languages/css.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlightjs-line-numbers.js/2.6.0/highlightjs-line-numbers.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.highlightAll(); hljs.initLineNumbersOnLoad();</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you mean top-right end of your code-blocks instead of bottom-left like now ?

Comment: Just add `pre{ position:relative;
}` to your css and it will work. That's why I added the same in my answer too.

Comment: could you see this updated https://jsfiddle.net/dsmith33/5jzbs94c/6/ not working, added copyHandler, but unknown - error("var elements not defined"), the variables(button) created could not be applied -